# Listening to current time change with an OSMF proxy plugin

Tags: plugins, osmf

I am trying to create a proxy plugin for OSMF that will serve as an analytics plugin, that tracks certain events. I want to track the current time of the video.

In the set method for the proxied element, I have the following:

```
proxiedElement.addEventListener(MediaElementEvent.TRAIT_ADD, _onTraitAdd);
```

Then, in the `_onTraitAdd` method, I am attaching event listeners for the DURATION_CHANGE and CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE events.

```
    private function _onTraitAdd(event:MediaElementEvent ):void {
        trace("adding trait");
        trace(event.traitType);

        if (MediaTraitType.TIME == event.traitType) 
        {
            //Get the time trait, so we can handle the duration changed event
            var timeTrait:TimeTrait = proxiedElement.getTrait( MediaTraitType.TIME ) as TimeTrait;
            timeTrait.addEventListener( TimeEvent.DURATION_CHANGE, _onDurationChanged );
            timeTrait.addEventListener( TimeEvent.CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE, _onTimeChanged );
            //debug( "Media has a timeline" );

        }

    }
```

The first event, `DURATION_CHANGE` is fired at the beginning of the video, however the second one is never fired.

On which element should I attach the `CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE` event in order to track the current time of the video?

I have analyzed the [Google Analytics plugin for OSMF](http://code.google.com/p/reops/wiki/GTrackPlugin) that claims to track every 5,10 or 20 seconds, however [looking at the code](http://code.google.com/p/reops/source/browse/trunk/src/com/realeyes/osmf/plugins/TrackerPluginInfo.as), it is not clear how it manages to track current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add the time change event listener on the media player.

First, one needs to pass a reference of the media player to the resource.

In the main class for plugin, add the following after defining the pluginResource.

```
pluginResource.addMetadataValue("MediaPlayer", mediaPlayer);
```

Then, in the class that extends PluginInfo, override the initializePlugin method. Get hold of the MediaPlayer reference, and add the event listener.

```
*/ 
override public function initializePlugin(resource:MediaResourceBase):void
{
var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer = resource.getMetadataValue("MediaPlayer") as MediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer.addEventListener(TimeEvent.CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE, _onTimeChanged);

 }

 private function _onTimeChanged(event:TimeEvent):void {

     trace("event.time", event.time);
  }
```

For more info, see the advertisement plugin included in the OSMF source files (`AdvertisementPluginInfo.as`).